# Add an anchor tag inside a php definition

Tags: php, json, email

I am trying to add a link inside a success message that is shown after a contact form is filled in and sent. But this is the output I get:

```
{"submit_message":"Bedankt voor uw vertrouwen in ons. Klik hier<\/a> voor meer informatie.","isValid":true}
```

And this is the code I use (config.php):

```
define('_msg_send_ok', 'Bedankt voor uw vertrouwen in ons. Klik <a href="informatie.php">hier</a> voor meer informatie.');
```

In my mail script itself:

```
if($isValid == true) {
        $result["submit_message"] = _msg_send_ok;
    } else {
        $result["submit_message"] = _msg_send_error;
    }

    $result['isValid'] = $isValid;

    echo json_encode($result);
```

How can I add an anchor tag that actually works? And how can I decode the json string into a more normal looking text? I tried it with json_decode, but that didn't work for me, maybe I did something wrong.